# Can we monitor Jboss using check_mk monitoring tool?

Tags: jboss, monitoring, nagios, check-mk

I have installed and configured `check_mk` tool. Also, configured its agents on both Windows and Linux servers.

Now, I can monitor things like CPU Utilization. But i want to check whether `JBoss` is running on server or not. If no, it will trigger an email notification to the particular email id.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom powershell scripts in windows and drop them into the local check_mk folder usually located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\check_mk\local". Once you've dropped the file into this folder you'll need to go into the Check_mk dashboard and add the new monitor to the servers inventory.

Below is a basic service monitor. This will allow you to monitor any service that you'd like.  Stats 0=OK, 1=Warning, 2=Critical, 3=Unknown

```
$serviceName='<any servce name>'
$status=get-service -name $serviceName
$jbossStatus=$status.Status

if ($jbossStatus -eq 'Running') {
    Write-Host "0 jboss_service - Status:" $jbossStatus
} 
else {
    write-host "2 jboss_service - Status: " $jbossStatus  
    }
```